# Integrating $\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{{\tanh}(a)-{\tanh}(x)}\;dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> What is the integral
>
> $$\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{{\tanh}(a)-{\tanh}(x)}\;dx$$

I have tried various substitutions but couldn't get the answer.

The substitution $x = {\tanh}^{-1}y$ has simplified into rational function in y but I couldn't proceed further.

I got

$$\int_{0}^{\tanh(a)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tanh(a)-y}}\frac{1}{1-y^{2}} \; .$$

Comment: How about trying with a substitution $\sqrt{\operatorname{tanh}(a) - \operatorname{tanh}{x}} = y$, instead? Might it work?

Comment: Typing tips: we use {} to indicate groups, \{\} to indicate a pair of braces. Your code has lots of uncompleted groups, hence the compiler cannot process them.

Comment: Where did you get this integral?

Comment: @FrankW. In quantum mechanics while using WKB method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^a \sqrt{\tanh a-\tanh x}dx\overset{\tanh x=y}=\int_0^{\tanh a} \sqrt{\tanh a-y}\ \frac{dy}{1-y^2}$$
Let us denote $\tanh a=n$ for now. And our first goal must be to get rid of the square root, thus a substitution of $n-y =t^2$ would fit great.
$$I=\int_0^n \frac{\sqrt{n-y}}{1-y^2}dy=\int^0_{\sqrt n}  \frac{t}{1-(n-t^2)^2}(-2t\,)dt=\int_0^{\sqrt n} \frac{2t^2}{1-(n-t^2)^2}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\sqrt n \frac{1+n}{1+n-t^2}dt-\int_0^\sqrt n \frac{1-n}{1-n+t^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{1+n}{\sqrt{1+n}}\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+n}}\right)\bigg|_0^\sqrt n-\frac{1-n}{\sqrt{1-n}}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-n}}\right)\bigg|_0^\sqrt n$$
$$={\sqrt{1+\tanh a}}\cdot \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{{\tanh a}}{1+\tanh a}}\right)-{\sqrt{1-\tanh a}}\cdot \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{{\tanh a}}{1-\tanh a}}\right)$$

Comment: This is the same as directly substituting the entire integrand with the new variable, is it not?

Comment: Pretty much yes, but it leaves a room to get rid of that $\tanh a$, also this was OP's approach so I continued.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Check if this approach is useful. The substitution
$$ y = \sqrt{\tanh(a)-\tanh(x)}$$
gives you
$$y^2 = \tanh(a)-\tanh(x),$$
and, therefore,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&2y dy = -(1-\tanh^2(x)) dx\\
&&2ydy = -\left[1-(\tanh(a)-y^2)^2\right] dx\\
&&\frac{2y dy}{(y^2-\tanh(a))^2-1} = dx.
\end{eqnarray}
Then the integral becomes rational, i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}\mathcal I &=& \int \sqrt{\tanh(a)-\tanh(x)}dx= \\
&=&2\int \frac{y^2dy}{{(y^2-\tanh(a))^2-1}}=\\
&=&2\int\frac{y^2dy}{(y^2-\tanh(a)-1)(y^2+1-\tanh(a))}=\\
&=& 2\int \frac{y^2dy}{(y-\sqrt{\tanh(a)+1})(y+\sqrt{\tanh(a)+1})(y^2+1-\tanh(a))},
\end{eqnarray}
recalling that $-1\leq \tanh(x) \leq 1$. You can proceed from here with partial fractions.